# Enable SSO in Salesforce Mobile on Andriod device

Tags: mobile, single-sign-on, federated-authentication

We are using Federated authentication for SSO and now I want this SSO in Salesforce mobile app running in Andriod devices.We were able to setup SSO in IOS devices ,but it is not allowing us to set custom domain on Andriod devices. Does anyone has implemented this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce is providing this option on Android devices now.